# nodejs GET using form and render route

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

By defining my route like this

```
router.get('/book/:book_id', function(req,res){
   console.log(res.body.book_id) //have value
});
```

I'm able to visit localhost:20/book/1, but in my jade I failed to do something which is clickable using form.

since one is a dynamic data I do like this

```
form(action="#{book.book_id}", method="get")
  input(type='submit',value='Submit')
```

It doesn't work..

Comment: And did you include a body-parser, and passed the value to the locals variable in your template ?

Comment: could you provide some more insight to your .jade and express route? like how what the form is supposed to do and what "doesn't work" and uhh your res.send or res.render

Comment: and where is /book/ in the action?

Comment: hey in your alon dir you got a file with name npm-debug.log   attach that file also

Comment: try `form(action="/book/#{book.book_id}"`